# How do you reference a WCF service in a COM interop enabled DLL?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, com, interop

**Problem Summary**: I have a C# DLL that is COM interop enabled/visible. This C# DLL has a service reference to a WCF service. When I instantiate the WCF service in the C# code, COM interop returns a error HRESULT (0x80131509).

**Problem Details**:
There are three components in my solution. The first is an unmanaged C++ application. This C++ application needs to communicate with a WCF service. The approach I decided on was to make a C# middle layer between the C++ application and the WCF service. The C# layer would be COM interop enabled/visible so that the C++ application could call into it and the C# code would handle talking to the WCF services. The C++ side would never need to know about the WCF services; the COM interop call would be a black box as far as it was concerned.

The problem arises when I try to instantiate the WCF service client in the C# code. To facilitate testing, I made a Test() method in the C# DLL. Calling Test() would simply return a hard-coded test string. This works. I am able to start up the C++ application, which calls into the C# DLL via COM interop, and the test string is returned. The HRESULT is S_OK. Now, if I change the Test() method by adding a *single* line that simply instantiates the WCF client, the COM interop call now returns an HRESULT of 0x80131509.

The only clue I have is that when I compile the C# DLL, I get the following warning:

> warning : Type library exporter warning processing '[my WCF service]'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a type that derives from a generic class and is not marked as [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]. Class interfaces cannot be exposed for such types. Consider marking the type with [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)] and exposing an explicit interface as the default interface to COM using the ComDefaultInterface attribute.

I don't know why it is giving me a warning about exporting the WCF service type. I was hoping that by using the C# middle layer, it could isolate the existence of the WCF services from the C++ application.

So what is the trick for using WCF services in a DLL that is COM enabled/visible?

Comment: What you want to do is definately possible - how did you create the WCF client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days of agony, a solution has been found, though it feels more like a work-around than a real solution.

I found a clue when I realized that when attempting to instantiate the WCF service in the C# code, an exception was thrown. After trapping the exception on the C++ side of things (a [CAtlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b1a94tx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to be exact) and looking at the HRESULT code, I determined that the C++ program was complaining because it couldn't find the WCF service bindings. Wait, what? Somewhat unbelieving, I created a .exe.config file and put it in the same directory as the executable. The .exe.config file basically contained the contents of the app.config from the WCF service project, plus an additional `client` tag in the `system.serviceModel` section that held a single `endpoint` tag pointing to the address of the WCF service. Everything worked fine with that in place.

It seems wrong to me though. Why should the C++ program need to know that? Just thinking logically, the C# COM interop should separate that knowledge and act as a barrier, totally encapsulating the WCF layer. By forcing the C++ program to know about the underlying structure, it defeats that encapsulation and makes everything all a little more...inelegant. It is entirely possible that I don't know how the messy innards of COM interop work, so maybe it all makes sense to someone.